# Reorder audio in Audacity

Tags: audacity

Let's say I have an mp3 with 2 distinct parts and silence separating them:

[image]

- 00:00:00 to 00:00:15 - first part of audio
- 00:00:15 to 00:00:30 - silence
- 00:00:30 to 00:00:45 - second part of audio

How can I skip the silence and reorder it to:

- 00:00:00 to 00:00:15 - second part of audio
- 00:00:15 to 00:00:30 - first part of audio

Comment: Are you asking how to do it automatically and regularly? If yes, then what are the criteria? If not, then what's the problem with cut and paste?

Comment: @techraf No, not automatically. Just manually. Audacity's interface is rather complex, and I have zero experience with it. I tried selecting them, but then I can't move the selection in time, it just makes a new selection.

Comment: Use you mouse to select a part of the track (press the left mouse key and move your mouse). Then press Ctrl+x; move the cursor to the position you want to paste and press Ctrl+v. This might result in a short click at the joint, which you can smooth out with tools, but I believe you are not there yet. You can also do it by trial and error until you get satisfying result.

Comment: @techraf Any reason you made that a comment and now an answer?